# Why should there be an article?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article

The sentence: "I took a few biology classes and read lots of books on ***the*** psychology and physiology of animals."

Comment: Tell us why you think there shouldn't be one ...

Comment: I am not a grammar expert. I wrote this sentence without "the" and checked with some proofreading software that added it. There was no explanation on why it should be there. I didn't put "the" there because I am not talking about some specific psychology.

Comment: There could be a rule that I just do not know about.

Comment: But you _are_ talking about a specific psychology - that of animals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't put "the" there because I am not talking about some specific psychology.

Well, it seems like you are!

> [Y]ou *are* talking about a specific psychology - that of animals! – Kate Bunting